# COMO SALVAR RETORNO DE UM SUBSCRIBE EM UMA VARIÁVEL?

Tags: angularjs, angular, http

Meu código base:

```
ngOnInit() {
const today = Date.now()
this._schedulesService.getSchedules().subscribe(      
  (res: SchedulesModel[]) => {
    this.schedulesToday = res
    this.schedulesToday.filter((schedule: SchedulesModel) => schedule.dtPlanejada == today.toString())
    this.schedulesToday.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.dtPlanejada = formatDate(obj.dtPlanejada)
      obj.containerdata = this._containersService.get__container__by_id(obj.idContainer)
    })
  }
)
```

}

Trecho do código que faz conexão com meu servidor.

```
get__container__by_id(id: string): Observable<ContainersModel> {
const token: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).token    
return this.http.get<ContainersModel>(`${API_URL}/containers/${id}`, setTokenHeader(token)).pipe(map(response => response))
```

}

Minha dúvida é: Como devo fazer para que a função `get__container_by_id(id)` retorno meu objeto direto para que o retorno seja armazenado direto na variável `obj.containerdata` ?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o seu contexto, seu problema é que o retorno da requisição não está sendo atribuido a ob.containerdata? Por ser uma requisição http, acredito que você deva fazer um subscribe no get_container_by_id também, e quando receber a resposta do servidor atribuir a containerdata, se puder explicar um pouco melhor o contexto talvez eu consiga ajudar melhor

Comment: Exatamente esse o problema. Não sei escrever o mapeamento correto de retorno da resposta do servidor. Já fiz subscribe no dois métodos e mesmo assim a resposta continua sendo um objeto Subscriber. Como eu deveria escrever para que o método `get__container_by_id()` devolvesse um objeto mapeado no tipo `ContainersModel` ?

Answer (score 0):

Cara no geral esse seu codigo ta bem ruim

```
ngOnInit() {
const today = Date.now()
this._schedulesService.getSchedules()
.pipe(
     map(response=>response.filter(item=>item.dtPlanejada == today.toString()).map(obj=>obj.id)),
mergeMap(
    ids=> {
      return combineLatest(ids.map(id=> this._containersService.get__container__by_id(id))).pipe(map(objs=> {
        return {
          objs
        }
      }))

 ).subscribe(response=>console.log(response)
```

Comment: O seu não melhorou nada e não funcionou. Mas eu resolvi, obrigado!